# How do you launch an html file that calls other html files in MVC?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm building a webpage that lists courses and allows a user to launch them.

When the user clicks the "Launch" button, it sends my HomeController the name of the folder that the course is sitting in. There's an html file in there called "launch".

My problem is that launch.html calls other html files. MVC is trying to force those files to load in the window as if they were all individual webpages, but they're partials (for example, ProductReview.html calls Login.html, Header.html, Footer.html, etc. to build one overall page).

I'm thinking that the solution to this is to make launch.html open in its own webpage, which operates independently of any models, views, or controllers. Is this possible?

Here's the code I've got right now:

```
public ActionResult Launch(string courseFolder)
{
    return File("~/Courses/" + courseFolder + "/_Images/ProductReview.html", "text/html");
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean "calls"? Like an href? An include? Why aren't you using cshtml files and the MVC framework features like routing? It sounds like you're fighting the intended methodology. I could be missing something.

Comment: The courses are pre-packaged, so I don't have any control over how they work internally. The only thing I'm using MVC for is to build a webpage to host the pre-packaged courses. The goal is to launch the HTML file at the top of the course's directory and then let the course handle everything else from there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to return a File.  You want to return a View.

But, more to the point, why don't you just build the URL you want on your landing page (with Razor or Javascript)?

Comment: For more info, see the comment I post in response to itsme86. tl;dr I don't have any control over what happens once I run the Launch.html file. I just need to get those files to run in their own window, and MVC is interfering with that (or so it seems)

Comment: Oh, so you want it to open in its own tab or window?  Are you using the window.open JS method on your base page (the one with the link)?  If not, that is one way to accomplish this.  Sorry if I am misunderstanding...

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm not using window.open; I'll give that a try. Thanks!